# Display a form only after installation in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a Windows form application in VB

I want to display a form only at the first application start up i.e. opening the form for the first time after installation , then it should not display the form . How to do it?

Comment: you do this by starting to write something on your own for starters.. secondly I would research and understand how Form.Show or ShowModal works.. also be more specific in regards to what you want to truly do after the form gets displayed  please show more effort on your part as well

Comment: For example you want to load a form for some configuration. Check if that configuration doesn't exist load your first-time form.

Comment: Ignore the people marking you down. They are ignorant and think everyone, even people new to StackOverflow should know exactly what they are doing on the site. You should normally show some code showing that you have tried to get the problem to work.

They don't know what they are doing either as they did not leave a message saying why they down voted you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this is normally done is by

1) setting a registry key FirstRun (you create this) to a value of False
   When you run your app for the first time you check the key if it exists (It won't at this    stage) then run the installation form which will set the key. So next time the program runs it checks the key and sees that it has been set and knows not to run the form.

2) This is the way I do it. Check if a folder or file belonging to the app exists if not run installation form and create the file, folder that you will check for. If it does exist then you know not to run the form.

```
If (!File.Exists("yourFile"))
   InstallForm.Show();
```